# Not able to change the background color of the header

Tags: html, css

trying to change the header background color , but its not changing, there is a body color red for the entire body, I want to only change the header portion background color which is not happening

please can somebody suggest me the what is going wrong

```
<html>
  <head>
    <metadata name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
    <metadata charset="utf-8"/>
    <metadata name="keywords" content="vasu">
  <style>
    body{
        background-color:red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    header {

        color: white;
        height: 80%;
        width: 90%;
        background-color:yellow;   --- need to changee color , not happening
    }
    header h1{
        float : left;
        padding : 0;
    }
    header ul{
        float : right;
        padding:0;

    }
  </style>
  </head>
    <body>
          <header>
            <div class="container">
            <div id="logo">
              <h1>ACME WEB DESIGN</h1>
            <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Hostel</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Company</a></li>
              <ul>  
            </nav>
             </div> 
             </div>

          </header>

          <section>
          </section>
           <footer>
           </footer>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: How about using `background-color:yellow !important;`?

Comment: It does work in Chrome. See screenshot: https://file.io/KsUux8

Comment: @wannadream, I could not open the screenshot, its not working , I am using chrome only

Comment: Set a height and width on your `<html>` tag in css: `html{height:100%; width:100%;`. Since no size is specified for the page, it's collapsing the child elements.  https://jsfiddle.net/9t3jhxus/3/

Comment: See this: https://unsee.cc/627f1ab2/

Comment: I have Chrome too and it works.

Answer (score 0):

it works for me but there is a small mistake , you did not close ul

```
         <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Hostel</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Company</a></li>
          </ul>  //here you forgot to close
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that when all the contents are floating the container has zero height, so you don't see the background. 
It works works for me when I change the following lines:

```
header h1{
    float : left;
    padding : 0;
}
header ul{
    float : right;
    padding:0;

}
```

to this:

```
 header h1 {
   display:inline-block;
   width:74%;
   padding: 0;
 }

 header nav {
   display:inline-block;
   width:24%;
   padding: 0;
 }
```